# System.XmlException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not {

Tags: apex, json, xml

I am getting above errror while try to make code coverage for my apex class.What went wrong how to overcome this.
Apex Class:

```
public class XeroController{
public List<Packing_Line_Item__c> OLI{get;set;}
public Packing__c PackRec{get;set;}
public List<String> ThemesId=new List<String>();
public List<SelectOption> ThemesName{get;set;}
public string AmountType{get;set;}
public Account Acc{get;set;} 
public string TaxIds,XeroAcctId;
Id PackingId;
boolean ErrFlag=false;

public XeroController(){
   string Accode;
   ThemesName=new List<SelectOption>();
   ThemesName.add(new SelectOption('',''));
   PackingId=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
   PackRec=[select id,Name,Opportunity__r.Name,Quote_No__c,Xero_Tax_Type__c,Packing_XeroId__c,Opportunity__r.Tax__r.Name,Opportunity__r.AccountId,Contact_Details__c,Total_VAT__c,Invoice_Total__c,Reference__c ,Amount__c,Opportunity__r.Date__c,Due_Date__c,Opportunity__r.Invoice_No__c,Opportunity__r.Account.OrganisationTaxDisplayName__c,Opportunity__r.Contact__r.Reference__c from Packing__c where id=:PackingId];

   Acc=[select id,Name,Phone,AccountNumber,Shippingcity,Shippingstate,ShippingPostalcode,Shippingcountry,XeroId__c from Account where id=:PackRec.Opportunity__r.AccountId];
   OLI=OLiList(PackingId);

             }

public List<Packing_Line_Item__c> OLiList(string PackingId){

    if(PackingId!=null){
    return [select Item__r.Name,Unit_Price__c,Quantity__c,Discount__c,VAT__c,Total_Price__c,Code__c,Description__c from Packing_Line_Item__c where Packing__c=:PackingId];
    }else{
    return null;
    }
}


public pagereference cancel(){
PageReference ReturnPage = new PageReference('/' +PackingId); 
ReturnPage.setRedirect(true); 
return ReturnPage;
 }

public pagereference PostOpportunity(){
   postOpptoXero(PackingId);

   PageReference ReturnPage = new PageReference('/' +PackingId); 
   ReturnPage.setRedirect(true); 

   if(!ErrFlag)
   return ReturnPage;

   return null;
}

public pagereference postOpptoXero(string opid){

String invoiceId,InvoiceNo;

  if(PackRec.Due_Date__c==null){
       ErrFlag=true;
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Please enter Due Date'));
       return null;
   }

   if(PackRec.Opportunity__r.Date__c>PackRec.Due_Date__c){
       ErrFlag=true;
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Due Date must be greaterthan Invoice Date'));
       return null;
   }

   if(PackRec.Due_Date__c<system.today()){
       ErrFlag=true;
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Due Date is already passed'));
       return null;
   }

   if(PackRec.Packing_XeroId__c==null){

   Xero_Oauth__c xeroSettings = Xero_Oauth__c.getInstance();
   HttpResponse response =new HttpResponse();
   HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    request.setBody(converttoXml());

    if(TaxIds=='Error'){
       ErrFlag=true;
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'The given Opportunity Tax Code not available in Xero'));
       return null;
    }

    request = XeroOAuthUtility.signRequest(request, xeroSettings.Consumer_Key__c);

    Http h=new Http();
    response=h.send(request);

    system.debug('contactXml>>>>>>>>'+converttoXml());

    if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
        Dom.Document doc = response.getBodyDocument();            
        Dom.XMLNode Inv= doc.getRootElement(); 

        for(Dom.XMLNode child : Inv.getChildElements()){
            for(Dom.XMLNode childField : child.getChildren()){
                system.debug('childField==='+childField);
                for(Dom.XMLNode childField1 : childField.getChildren()){
                system.debug('childField1==='+childField1);
                if(childField1.getName()=='InvoiceID')
                invoiceId=childField1.getText();
                if(childField1.getName()=='InvoiceNumber')
                InvoiceNo=childField1.getText();
                }
            }
        }           
        PackRec.Due_Date__c=PackRec.Due_Date__c;
        PackRec.Xero_Invoice_No__c=InvoiceNo;
        PackRec.Packing_XeroId__c=invoiceId;
        update PackRec;

        if(Acc.XeroId__c==null){
        Acc.XeroId__c=XeroAcctId;
        update Acc;
        }
    } 
   }  
   return null;
}

public class Items{
   public string code;
}

public void CheckItemAvail(String ProductCodes, String PrdDesc){
    List<Items> xeroContact = new List<Items>();
    Xero_Oauth__c xeroSettings = Xero_Oauth__c.getInstance();
    HttpResponse response =new HttpResponse();

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Items/'+ProductCodes);
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request = XeroOAuthUtility.signRequest(request, xeroSettings.Consumer_Key__c);

    Http h=new Http();
    response=h.send(request);
    h=new Http();
    if(response.getStatusCode()==404){
     request = new HttpRequest();
     String ItemsInsert=''+'<Items>'+
                            '<Item>'+
                            '<Code>'+ProductCodes+'</Code>'+
                            '<Description>'+PrdDesc+'</Description>'+
                            '</Item>'+
                            '</Items>';
      ItemsInsert ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +  ItemsInsert;
      request.setMethod('POST');
      request.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Items');
      request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
      request.setBody(ItemsInsert);
      request = XeroOAuthUtility.signRequest(request, xeroSettings.Consumer_Key__c);
      response=h.send(request);
    }
}

public string contacts(string contactNmae){
    List<XeroContact> xeroContact = new List<XeroContact>();
    Xero_Oauth__c xeroSettings = Xero_Oauth__c.getInstance();
    HttpResponse response =new HttpResponse();

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    request.setMethod('GET');
    string uri_enc = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactNmae, 'UTF-8');
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts?where=Name%3D%3D"'+uri_enc+'"');
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    request = XeroOAuthUtility.signRequest(request, xeroSettings.Consumer_Key__c);

    Http h=new Http();
    response=h.send(request);
    List<XeroContact> conList=new List<XeroContact>();
     if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        xeroContact = XeroCalloutResponseParser.parseContacts(response.getBody());
          if(xeroContact!=null && xeroContact.size()>0)
        return xeroContact[0].ContactID;
        else
        return null;
    }

    return null;        
}

public string PostContact(string accids){

       if(Acc.XeroId__c==null){
           XeroContact ConRes;
           XeroContact newContact = new XeroContact();
           newContact.Name=Acc.Name;
           newContact.ContactNumber=Acc.Phone!=null?Acc.Phone:'';
           newContact.AccountNumber=Acc.AccountNumber!=null?Acc.AccountNumber:'';
           newContact.City=Acc.Shippingcity!=null?Acc.Shippingcity:'';
           newContact.PostalCode=Acc.ShippingPostalcode!=null?Acc.ShippingPostalcode:'';
           newContact.Country=Acc.Shippingcountry!=null?Acc.Shippingcountry:'';
           newContact.IsCustomer=true;
           newContact.IsSupplier=false;
           system.debug('>>>>>'+newContact);
           ConRes=XeroAccountingApi.createContact(XeroXmlUtility.serialize(newContact, 'Contact'));
           Acc.XeroId__c=ConRes.ContactID;
           return ConRes.ContactID;
       }
       return null;
}

public string converttoXml(){
String Accode;

   ErrFlag=false;

   if(PackRec.Opportunity__r.Tax__c!=null){
   XeroAccount XerAcc=new XeroAccount();
       //TaxIds=XerAcc.createAccount(PackRec.Opportunity__r.Tax__r.Name);
       TaxIds=PackRec.Opportunity__r.Tax__r.Tax_Type__c;
       Accode=PackRec.Opportunity__r.Tax__r.Name;
   }else{
       List<Tax__c> DefaultCode=new List<Tax__c>([select Tax_Type__c,Name from Tax__c where Percentage__c=10]);
       TaxIds=DefaultCode.size()>0?String.valueof(DefaultCode[0].Tax_Type__c):PackRec.Xero_Tax_Type__c;
       Accode=String.valueof(DefaultCode[0].Name);
   }

   if(AmountType=='Tax Exclusive')
       AmountType='Exclusive';
   else if(AmountType=='Tax Inclusive')
       AmountType='Inclusive';
   else
       AmountType='NoTax';

   //Accode=PackRec.Opportunity__r.Tax__c!=null?PackRec.Opportunity__r.Tax__r.Name:PackRec.Xero_Tax_Type__c;

   string contactXml =''+
   '<Invoice>'+  
   '<Contact>'+  
   '<ContactID>'+(contacts(Acc.name)!=null?contacts(Acc.name):PostContact(Acc.Id))+'</ContactID>'+  
   '</Contact>'+ 
   '<Type>ACCREC</Type>'+   
   '<Date>'+PackRec.Opportunity__r.Date__c+'</Date>'+
   '<DueDate>'+PackRec.Due_Date__c+'</DueDate>'+
   '<Reference>'+PackRec.Reference__c+'</Reference>'+
   '<LineAmountTypes>'+AmountType+'</LineAmountTypes>'+
   '<InvoiceDate>'+PackRec.Opportunity__r.Date__c+'</InvoiceDate>'+ '<LineItems>';
   for(Packing_Line_Item__c oliitms :OLI){

            string subStr = oliitms.Code__c!=null?oliitms.Code__c:oliitms.Item__r.name;
            subStr=subStr.length()<30?subStr:subStr.substring(0,30);

            if(oliitms.Code__c!=null && oliitms.Code__c!=''){
                CheckItemAvail(oliitms.Code__c,oliitms.Item__r.name);
            }else{
                CheckItemAvail(subStr,oliitms.Item__r.Description);
            }

            //CheckItemAvail(oliitms.Code__c,oliitms.Item__r.name);

            contactXml = contactXml +   
            '<LineItem>'+  
                '<Description>'+oliitms.Item__r.name +'</Description>'+
                '<Quantity>'+oliitms.Quantity__c+'</Quantity>'+
                '<UnitAmount>'+oliitms.Unit_Price__c+'</UnitAmount>'+
                '<TaxType>'+TaxIds+'</TaxType>'+
                '<AccountCode>'+Accode+'</AccountCode>'+
                //'<AccountCode>270</AccountCode>'+
                //'<DiscountRate>'+oliitms.Discount__c+'</DiscountRate>'+
                '<ItemCode>'+oliitms.Code__c+'</ItemCode>'+
            '</LineItem>'; 
      }
      contactXml = contactXml +   '</LineItems>'+  
      '<Status>Draft</Status>'+ 
      '</Invoice>'; 
      contactXml = contactXml + '</Invoices>';
      contactXml = '<Invoices>' + contactXml ;
      contactXml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +  contactXml;     
      system.debug('contactXmlcontactXmlcontactXmlcontactXmlcontactXml>>>>'+contactXml); 
      return contactXml;

}
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest(seeAlldata=true)
Public Class XeroControllerTest{
 @isTest Public static void XeroControllerMethod() {  

    StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
    mock.setStaticResource('XeroControllerSample');
    mock.setStatusCode(200);
    mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    mock.setHeader('Accept', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

    PricebookEntry priceBookEntryNew = new PricebookEntry();
    Product2 product = new Product2(); 

    Id pb2= Test.getStandardPricebookId();

    product.name = 'Test';
    product.ProductCode='Test';
    insert product;

    priceBookEntryNew.Product2Id = product.Id;
    priceBookEntryNew.PriceBook2Id = pb2;
    priceBookEntryNew.UnitPrice = 20.00;
    priceBookEntryNew.isactive = true;
    insert priceBookEntryNew;

    Contact newContact=new Contact(LastName='Test Contact');
    insert newContact;

Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
PricebookEntry pbID = [select Id, name from PricebookEntry where isActive =  True limit 1];
Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
OpportunityLineItem ol = new OpportunityLineItem();

insert a;

o.AccountId = a.Id;
o.Name = 'Test';
o.StageName = 'Prospecting';
o.CloseDate = date.today();
o.Pricebook2Id=pb2;
o.Type = 'New Business';
insert o;

    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem
        (
            OpportunityId = o.Id,
            PricebookEntryId = priceBookEntryNew.Id,
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = priceBookEntryNew.UnitPrice, 
            ServiceDate = System.today()

        );
  insert oli;

  Packing__c pa=new Packing__c();
        pa.Job__c = 'test job';
        pa.Opportunity__c=o.id;
        pa.Due_Date__c=System.today()+2;
   insert pa;

    test.starttest();

    apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('id',String.valueof(pa.id));
    XeroController XeroCtrl=new XeroController();
    XeroCtrl.PostOpportunity();
    XeroCtrl.cancel();
    XeroCtrl.contacts('test');
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Static Resource:

```
{
"Id": "18a7eaec-f113-4116-b94e-137701395334",
"Status": "OK",
"ProviderName": "CheckPointProducts",
"DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(1486649313628)\/",
"Contacts": [
 {
  "ContactID": "63d1c94d-448c-4a72-8a59-1753438e6e42",
  "ContactNumber": "",
  "ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "Name": "Merfantz Test Customer xero new",
  "EmailAddress": "",
  "BankAccountDetails": "",
  "Addresses": [
    {
      "AddressType": "STREET",
      "City": "",
      "Region": "",
      "PostalCode": "",
      "Country": ""
    },
    {
      "AddressType": "POBOX",
      "City": "",
      "Region": "",
      "PostalCode": "",
      "Country": ""
    }
  ],
  "Phones": [
    {
      "PhoneType": "DEFAULT",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneAreaCode": "",
      "PhoneCountryCode": ""
    },
    {
      "PhoneType": "DDI",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneAreaCode": "",
      "PhoneCountryCode": ""
    },
    {
      "PhoneType": "FAX",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneAreaCode": "",
      "PhoneCountryCode": ""
    },
    {
      "PhoneType": "MOBILE",
      "PhoneNumber": "",
      "PhoneAreaCode": "",
      "PhoneCountryCode": ""
    }
  ],
  "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1486649313597+0000)\/",
  "ContactGroups": [],
  "IsSupplier": false,
  "IsCustomer": false,
  "SalesTrackingCategories": [],
  "PurchasesTrackingCategories": [],
  "ContactPersons": [],
  "HasValidationErrors": false
}
]
}
```

I have errors in following lines.
Class.XeroController.postOpptoXero: line 100, column 1 
Class.XeroController.PostOpportunity: line 42, column 1
Class.XeroControllerTest.XeroControllerMethod: line 67, column 1

Comment: Google has a lot of information have you tried there? It appears it could be  many things

Comment: I tried google but I didn't understand  exactly why this error come.Do you have any suggestions here to change my code

Comment: The first article I read was talking about you need to escape certain characters, I stopped reading once i saw there was 15+ results to my search
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fzvZIAQ#!/feedtype=RECENT&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&

Comment: So how can I overcome this problem should I try every possible things as you told it could be many things

Answer (score 1):

You don't post the source code for `StaticResourceCalloutMock`, but if what it does is return the JSON static resource you have posted, the problem is that your product code is expecting [XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp) but you are feeding it [JSON](http://json.org/) that starts with `{` rather than `<`. Change the static resource to contain the expected data in XML format.

I also suggest that at some point you re-implement the `converttoXml` method to not build the XML using string concatenation but instead to use the Apex [Dom](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Dom.htm) classes. You build the structure then call `toXmlString` at the end. This will make the code easier to understand but most importantly will ensure that the appropriate escaping is applied to the text strings.